# Recovery root password PostgreSQL on Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql

I forgot password on database, and want to reset it, but I have fatal error on TRUST in file pg_hba.conf:

```
# host all all all md5
# host all all 127.0.0.1/32 trust
# local all postgres md5
# host all all all ident
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust 

# IPv4 local connections:
# host all all 10.32.32.26/32 ident map=map1
# host all all 127.0.0.1/32 ident map=map1
# host all all 127.0.0.1/32 sspi map=map1
```

invalid authentication method "trust"

I try to make IDENT and SSPI with mapping of real user, but I have error:
password authentication failed for user ...

Last try of pg_ident.conf file:

```
map1  /.+  postgres
```

Virsion: (PostgreSQL) 9.1.15 on Windows 7

What I am doing wrong?

Full Error on start:

> C:\Program Files (x86)...\server\bin>pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files (x86)...\database" start
>
> server starting
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)...\server\bin>LOG:  invalid authentication method "trust"
>
> CONTEXT:  line 5 of configuration file "C:/Program Files (x86)/.../database/pg_hba.conf"
>
> FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf

Comment: That `pg_hba.conf` file looks fine. `invalid connection type "trust"` would mean that there is a line that *starts* with `trust`, but I cannot see such a line. Is that an old log entry from a previous attempt or is it caused by the current `pg_hba.conf` upon server restart? Are there any "invisible" characters in the file?

Comment: I am too sorry, in line 16 was "trust" when I try... It`s not error, error in line 5. And Now I have only one line, and same error - invalid authentication method "trust"  (((

Comment: Can you update the query with the single line `pg_hba.conf` and the error on server start? Did you look at the file with a hex editor?

Comment: See this answer: [Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44588)